# How to modify a json response to include own keys instead it being created by itself in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I have two models category and sub_category

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sub_categories
```

and

```
class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
```

now in my sub_category controller i have

```
@sub_category = SubCategory.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page]).all(:order => 'id ASC')
respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render json: {:sub_category => @sub_category.as_json(:only => [:id, :name, :category_id, :created_at, :updated_at])} }
      end
```

but i want the category object to which the subcategory belongs_to within this as shown below

```
    [
    {
    "sub_category":
    [{
    "created_at":"2013-09-25T07:16:53Z",
    "id":2,
    "name":"mobile",
    "updated_at":"2013-09-25T07:19:39Z"
    "category":{"id":1, "name":"gadgets"}
    }]
    }
    ]
```

How can i do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@sub_category = Subcategory.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page]).order('id ASC').includes(:category)
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: {:sub_category => @sub_category.as_json(
    :only => [:id, :name, :category_id, :created_at, :updated_at],
    :include => {:category => {:only => [:id, :name])} }
end
```

Comment: Thankyou, I have been trying this but what i did is
    :include => [:categories] instead of :include => [:category]. So thankyou anyway.

Comment: one more doubt. In category i can use :include => [:sub_categories] but can i able to limit the number of sub_categories to be included. May be we can define it in model but i wanted to limit in only this response. Is this is possible?

Comment: @Logesh basically, you can't because of how eager loading works.

Comment: ok. Is there some other way to restrict or can i be able to do like this Category.includes(:sub_categories).first or anything similar. Actually I wanted to fetch the categories along with the first sub_category.